# Even columns with text padding?

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to website building and I ran into my first bigger problem with CSS. I'm having a simple 3-column split like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="featureSingle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit...</div>
<div class="featureSingle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit...</div>
<div class="featureSingle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit...</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.featureSingle {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    padding-right: 5px; 
}
```

The problem is with padding-right (I'd like padding-left and right anyway), basically it screws up the layout and moves third column below (it simply is too big). I thought padding changes text align inside of the container and that it shouldn't make it 'bigger'? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;`:

```
.featureSingle
{
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    padding-right: 5px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
         -o-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

fixed in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y9Jw2/

The default box model dosent take into account the `padding-right` your adding, so the end result is a width of 33% + the 5px of padding. This makes the total amount of space your columns are taking up to be over 100% of the browser window; so it doesn't fit all on one line. By changing the box model to `border-box` it allows the 33% width to take the padding into account, thus making the total 100% and allowing everything to fit.

Here's a great article by CSS Tricks that can explain it more detail: http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/.

Comment: May want to include `-moz-box-sizing` in the mix as well.

Comment: @user1255410 no problem! definitely check out the article I linked. it really helps wrap your mind around the way the box model works.

Comment: @user1255410 if I answered your question, can you please accept my answer?